# jackd does not work, aplay -l shows two instances of the same card (Ubuntu 13.04, HDMI audio only)

Tags: sound, hdmi, alsa, jack

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, using a ZaReason Zini, which as far as I can tell has no audio output other than its hdmi port. I'm trying to get the Clojure library Overtone working, and ran into the problem described [here](http://notesintheattic.blogspot.com/2012/10/problem-starting-overtone-on-ubuntu.html). The underlying problem seems to be that jackd doesn't work:

```
anand@anand-desktop:~$ jackd -R -d alsa
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

Following the blog post and advice others have given for similar problems, I did `aplay -l` and saw

```
anand@anand-desktop:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

There seem to be two instances of the same card. Doing `jackd -R -d alsa -d hw:0` produces the original error, and any other device number results in

```
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1401:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
```

Unfortunately, that means that the standard fix described in the blog post doesn't work for me. How can I get jackd working?

Comment: I should note that [this ppa](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages) is installed on my computer. Before I installed it, the sound didn't work at all.

Comment: From lspci: `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well `jackd -R -d alsa -d hw:0,3` seems to work:

```
jackdmp 1.9.10
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2013 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
no message buffer overruns
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0,3|hw:0,3|1024|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
```

I guess I now need to figure out how to get Overtone to use that extra option.

Comment: In case anyone gets here while trying to get Overtone to work, the solution is to simply run the command above in a separate terminal window or in the background, then start Overtone. Overtone automatically connects to the running jackd instance.

Comment: Spot on. Worked for me as well. Just had to use different values from the ```aplay -l``` command in the format ```-d hw:CARD,DEVICE``` . For my setup, for example, it was ```jackd -R -P4 -dalsa -d hw:1,0```. Now the sound making software I'm using, [din](http://dinisnoise.org), works! Interesting that when jackd is up, it prevents other audio playing (like youtube/vimeo videos) from carrying on. I guess because the audio interface has been repurposed. Exiting jackd let's them carry on as usual.

Comment: Keep in mind that you also have to set the input and output device in qjackctl setup->settings->advanced

Comment: @Anand this also works for Supercollider, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

For me, changing the output device in QjackCtl's settings from (defualt) to HW:PCH,0 solved the problem.

Here is the output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1802 Alt Analog [VT1802 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Yes! Your hint was the one that worked! Thanks a lot.